# Sqlite - SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE 'a%' ; NOT WORKING?

Tags: sqlite, select, sql-like

I have this table called `tbl`:

```
name    |  family

ali     |  rezaei
amir    |  hoseini
milad   |  karimi
alireza |  amiri
hossein |  mahmoodi
```

I write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE '%a%';
```

It worked and it returned:

> ali , amir , milad , alireza

BUT when I write this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE 'a%';
```

It didn't return anything!

`LIKE 'something%'` is not working for me, but `LIKE '%something'` and `LIKE '%something%'` work.

Comment: Looks like SQLite thinks that the letters are not the first characters in the text. Are you 100% sure that there is no whitespace at the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

`... WHERE name LIKE '%a%'` will find an **a** (or A) anywhere in the name column.

`... WHERE name LIKE 'a%'` will be limited to finding **a** (or A) only as the first character of the name column, as such it appears that a character, perhaps a whitespace character,  precedes the first character.

The ideal/correct solution would be to look at how the rows are being inserted and see if only the value itself is being inserted.

A solution could be to use `WHERE LTRIM(name) LIKE 'a%';` which would remove white-space from the start before doing the comparison.

The following is an example using 2 sets of your data, to demonstrate.

- The first set of data is as how you expect the data to be stored.
- The 2nd set is the data with a preceding white-space (space) character.

:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl (name TEXT, family TEXT);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
    ('ali','rezaei'),
    ('amir','hoseini'),
    ('milad','karimi'),
    ('alireza','amiri'),
    ('hossein','mahmoodi'),
    (' ali','rezaei'),
    (' amir','hoseini'),
    (' milad','karimi'),
    (' alireza','amiri'),
    (' hossein','mahmoodi')
;
```

3 Queries that are then run :-

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE '%a%';
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE name LIKE 'a%';
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE LTRIM(name) LIKE 'a%';
```

The first query, using the `'%a%'`, will return all rows with an **`a`** anywhere in the name column (4 of the 5 rows contain a in the name column per set so for 2 sets 8 in total); as per :-

[image]

The second query is the most selective and will only return 3 rows from the first set of data because the **a** is the first character, whilst the similar rows from the second set will not be returned because the a's are preceded with a space (this suspected scenario); as per :-

[image]

The third query an adaptation of the second that trims the leading white-spaces (spaces) returns 3 rows from each set; as per :-

[image]